# Servo Parallel Browser Engine Project - doesn't work in windows?

Tags: rust, browser, chromium, servo

https://github.com/servo/servo

I tried to setup this open-source pure browser on my local and according to their read me `mach bootstrap` would help me to install `CMake, Git, Ninja, Python and the Visual Studio 2019 Build Tools via choco in an Administrator console. It can take quite a while.`

But when I tried `mach bootstrap`, it shows nothing.

[image]

Comment: Did you follow the preceding steps: installing Rust and Chocolatey? Looking at what `mach` does, it looks like you'd need Python as well.

Comment: yes, i did. so installed rust and chocolately correctly.